# Convert two types into a single type with Serde

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, serde

I'm writing for a program that hooks into a web service which sends back JSON.

When a certain property isn't there it provides a empty object, with all its fields as empty strings instead of excluding the value. When the property exists, some of the properties are `u64`. How can I have it so Serde handles this case?

### Rust Structs

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct WebResponse {
    foo: Vec<Foo>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    points: Points,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Points {
    x: u64,
    y: u64,
    name: String,
}
```

### Example JSON

```
{
    "foo":[
        {
            "points":{
                "x":"",
                "y":"",
                "name":""
            }
        },
        {
            "points":{
                "x":78,
                "y":92,
                "name":"bar"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What should happen when you get an empty string instead of a `u64`? Do you want to set the field to `0`? to `None`? something else?

Comment: @FrancisGagné I think it would be `0`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Serde supports an interesting selection of [attributes](https://serde.rs/attributes.html) that can be used to customize the serialization or deserialization for a type while still using the derived implementation for the most part.

In your case, you need to be able to decode a field that can be specified as one of multiple types, and you don't need information from other fields to decide how to decode the problematic fields. The `#[serde(deserialize_with="$path")]` annotation is well suited to solve your problem.

We need to define a function that will decode either an empty string or an integer value into an `u64`. We can use the same function for both fields, since we need the same behavior. This function will use a custom [`Visitor`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.15/serde/de/trait.Visitor.html) to be able to handle both strings and integers. It's a bit long, but it makes you appreciate all the work that Serde is doing for you!

```
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::Deserializer;
use serde::de::{self, Unexpected};
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct WebResponse {
    foo: Vec<Foo>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    points: Points,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Points {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_u64_or_empty_string")]
    x: u64,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_u64_or_empty_string")]
    y: u64,
    name: String,
}

struct DeserializeU64OrEmptyStringVisitor;

impl<'de> de::Visitor<'de> for DeserializeU64OrEmptyStringVisitor {
    type Value = u64;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("an integer or a string")
    }

    fn visit_u64<E>(self, v: u64) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
    where
        E: de::Error,
    {
        Ok(v)
    }

    fn visit_str<E>(self, v: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
    where
        E: de::Error,
    {
        if v == "" {
            Ok(0)
        } else {
            Err(E::invalid_value(Unexpected::Str(v), &self))
        }
    }
}

fn deserialize_u64_or_empty_string<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<u64, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    deserializer.deserialize_any(DeserializeU64OrEmptyStringVisitor)
}

fn main() {
    let value = serde_json::from_str::<WebResponse>(
        r#"{
        "foo": [
            {
                "points": {
                    "x": "",
                    "y": "",
                    "name": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "points": {
                    "x": 78,
                    "y": 92,
                    "name": "bar"
                }
            }
        ]
    }"#,
    );
    println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

---

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
serde = "1.0.15"
serde_json = "1.0.4"
serde_derive = "1.0.15"
```

Answer (score 11):

In `str_or_u64`, we use an [*untagged enum*](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) to represent either a string or a number. We can then deserialize the field into that enum and convert it to a number.

We annotate the two fields in `Points` using [`deserialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with) to tell it to use our special conversion:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer}; // 1.0.124
use serde_json; // 1.0.64

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct WebResponse {
    foo: Vec<Foo>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    points: Points,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Points {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "str_or_u64")]
    x: u64,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "str_or_u64")]
    y: u64,
    name: String,
}

fn str_or_u64<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<u64, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    #[serde(untagged)]
    enum StrOrU64<'a> {
        Str(&'a str),
        U64(u64),
    }

    Ok(match StrOrU64::deserialize(deserializer)? {
        StrOrU64::Str(v) => v.parse().unwrap_or(0), // Ignoring parsing errors
        StrOrU64::U64(v) => v,
    })
}

fn main() {
    let input = r#"{
        "foo":[
            {
                "points":{
                    "x":"",
                    "y":"",
                    "name":""
                }
            },
            {
                "points":{
                    "x":78,
                    "y":92,
                    "name":"bar"
                }
            }
        ]
    }"#;

    dbg!(serde_json::from_str::<WebResponse>(input));
}
```

See also:

- [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a note for future viewers: in case it is helpful, I have implemented the solution from the accepted answer and published it as a crate [`serde-this-or-that`](https://crates.io/crates/serde-this-or-that).

I've added a section on [Performance](https://github.com/rnag/serde-this-or-that#performance) to explain that an approach with a custom `Visitor` as suggested, should perform overall much better than a version with an [*untagged enum*](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged), which does also work.

Here is a shortened implementation of the accepted solution above (should have the same result):

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json::from_str;
use serde_this_or_that::as_u64;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct WebResponse {
    foo: Vec<Foo>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    points: Points,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Points {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "as_u64")]
    x: u64,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "as_u64")]
    y: u64,
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let value = from_str::<WebResponse>(
        r#"{
        "foo": [
            {
                "points": {
                    "x": "",
                    "y": "",
                    "name": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "points": {
                    "x": 78,
                    "y": 92,
                    "name": "bar"
                }
            }
        ]
    }"#,
    );
    println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

---

The `Cargo.toml` would look like:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.136", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.79"
serde-this-or-that = "0.4"
```