# Handling mixed object arrays in Serde

Tags: json, serialization, rust, serde

Expanding on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870428/convert-two-types-into-a-single-type-with-serde), how do you handle an array that contains mixed `structs` that are both valid? I've tried looking at the [`serde_json::Value`](https://serde-rs.github.io/json/src/serde_json/src/value.rs.html#74-98) source. However it doesn't handle the case of two different `structs`.

I can't simply merge them, and use Options over their properties as that would make the single `struct` unwieldy, and it is important for them to be distinct.

### Rust structs

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct WebResponse {
    foo: Vec<Structs>,
}

enum Structs {
    Foo(Foo),
    Bar(Bar),
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    name: String,
    baz: Vec<String>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Bar {
    quux: u64
}
```

### Example JSON

```
{
    "foo": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "baz": ["Lorem", "Ipsum"]
        },
        {
            "quux": 17
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few ways to solve this. The easiest, if you have few variants, is to simply implement `Deserialize` manually like so:

```
impl serde::de::Deserialize for Structs {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: &mut D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
        where D: serde::Deserializer,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize(Visitor)
    }
}

struct Visitor;

impl serde::de::Visitor for Visitor {
    type Value = Structs;

    fn visit_map<V>(&mut self, mut visitor: V) -> Result<Structs, V::Error>
        where V: serde::de::MapVisitor,
    {
        let s: String = try!(visitor.visit_key()).expect("got struct with no fields");
        let val = match &s as &str {
            "name" => {
                Ok(Structs::Foo(Foo {
                    name: try!(visitor.visit_value()),
                    baz: {
                        let s: String = try!(visitor.visit_key()).expect("baz field");
                        assert_eq!(&s, "baz");
                        try!(visitor.visit_value())
                    },
                }))
            },
            "baz" => {
                Ok(Structs::Foo(Foo {
                    baz: try!(visitor.visit_value()),
                    name: {
                        let s: String = try!(visitor.visit_key()).expect("name field");
                        assert_eq!(&s, "name");
                        try!(visitor.visit_value())
                    },
                }))
            },
            "quux" => {
                Ok(Structs::Bar(Bar {
                    quux: try!(visitor.visit_value())
                }))
            },
            other => panic!("no struct has field `{}`", other),
        };
        try!(visitor.end());
        val
    }
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that it obviously doesn't scale. What you can do instead, is to create a new `Deserializer` that you give the first field name that was found and override the `deserialize_map` method to process the various structs through a custom `MapVisitor`.

If you feel that this is a common case supported by other serialization frameworks, feel free to post a bug report on the `serde` repository or the `serde-json` repository. I'm sure there's a way to automatically generate such an implementation, but it's not trivial for sure.