# How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?

Tags: rust, hex, serde

I'm using Serde to deserialize an XML file which has the hex value `0x400` as a string and I need to convert it to the value `1024` as a `u32`.

Do I need to implement the `Visitor` trait so that I separate 0x and then decode 400 from base 16 to base 10? If so, how do I do that so that deserialization for base 10 integers remains intact?

Answer (score 78):

#### The `deserialize_with` attribute

The easiest solution is to use the [Serde field attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) [`deserialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with) to set a custom serialization function for your field. You then can get the raw string and [convert it as appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381414/converting-hexadecimal-string-to-decimal):

```
use serde::{de::Error, Deserialize, Deserializer}; // 1.0.94
use serde_json; // 1.0.40

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct EtheriumTransaction {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "from_hex")]
    account: u64, // hex
    amount: u64, // decimal
}

fn from_hex<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<u64, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s: &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    // do better hex decoding than this
    u64::from_str_radix(&s[2..], 16).map_err(D::Error::custom)
}

fn main() {
    let raw = r#"{"account": "0xDEADBEEF", "amount": 100}"#;
    let transaction: EtheriumTransaction =
        serde_json::from_str(raw).expect("Couldn't derserialize");
    assert_eq!(transaction.amount, 100);
    assert_eq!(transaction.account, 0xDEAD_BEEF);
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=83c99d83e5bf34c0238c0aaf900135a8)

Note how this can use any other existing Serde implementation to decode. Here, we decode to a string slice (`let s: &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?`). You can also create intermediate structs that map directly to your raw data, derive `Deserialize` on them, then deserialize to them inside your implementation of `Deserialize`.

#### Implement `serde::Deserialize`

From here, it's a tiny step to promoting it to your own type to allow reusing it:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct EtheriumTransaction {
    account: Account, // hex
    amount: u64,      // decimal
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Account(u64);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Account {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let s: &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        // do better hex decoding than this
        u64::from_str_radix(&s[2..], 16)
            .map(Account)
            .map_err(D::Error::custom)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=614bd7ad5aada5d7bd4109b9d45a6620)

This method allows you to also add or remove fields as the "inner" deserialized type can do basically whatever it wants.

#### The `from` and `try_from` attributes

You can also place the custom conversion logic from above into a `From` or `TryFrom` implementation, then instruct Serde to make use of that via the [`from`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#from) or [`try_from`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#try_from) attributes:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct EtheriumTransaction {
    account: Account, // hex
    amount: u64,      // decimal
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize)]
#[serde(try_from = "IntermediateAccount")]
struct Account(u64);

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct IntermediateAccount<'a>(&'a str);

impl<'a> TryFrom<IntermediateAccount<'a>> for Account {
    type Error = std::num::ParseIntError;

    fn try_from(other: IntermediateAccount<'a>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        // do better hex decoding than this
        u64::from_str_radix(&other.0[2..], 16).map(Self)
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How to transform fields during serialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39383809/155423)

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster. This is exactly what I'm looking for. The only issue is with the reference to the string as I get this panic msg: invalid type: string "0x400", expected a borrowed string.

Comment: @phodina Both of my examples run successfully, so evidently you've changed something. I am not a mind reader, so I don't know what that difference is. You could try `let s: String = ...` in case the XML decoder cannot provide string slices.

Comment: I've tried both of your examples in playground and on my PC and they both work. The issue comes up when I change the underlying format from json to xml. Here is the code (playground misses crate serde_xml_rs)
    let raw = r#"<EtheriumTransaction><account>0xDEADBEEF</account><amount>100</amount></EtheriumTransaction>"#;
    let transaction: EtheriumTransaction = serde_xml_rs::deserialize(raw.as_bytes()).unwrap();

Comment: @phodina yes, it appears that switching to `let s: String` [as I suggested earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753955/how-to-transform-fields-before-deserialization-using-serde/46755370#comment80464104_46755370) works.