# How do I customize a Deserialize implementation for certain input types but not all of them?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I have a type like this, although my actual type is bigger and more complex:

```
struct MyType {
    i: u32,
}
```

If I implement `Deserialize` for this type, serde looks for something like this (I'm interested in JSON):

```
{"i":100}
```

I want to customize it so that I can deserialize from a byte array as well:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I can write an impl to handle the array, but I want serde to auto generate the rest (which will be `visit_map`):

```
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyType {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct MyTypeVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for MyTypeVisitor {
            type Value = MyType;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                write!(formatter, "struct or array of 4 integers")
            }

            fn visit_seq<A: SeqAccess<'de>>(self, seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error> {
                // ...
            }
        }

        // deserializer.deserialize_any(MyTypeVisitor)
    }
}
```

Is that possible? In this example, it's not difficult, but when the struct is large, hand writing deserialization can be painful.

This is not a duplicate of [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423) because `deserialize_with` works only for 1 field. I can't understand how I would make it work for my real type:

```
pub enum Component {
    String(StringComponent),
    Translation(TranslationComponent),
    Score(ScoreComponent),
    Selector(SelectorComponent),
}

pub struct StringComponent {
    #[serde(flatten)] pub base: Base,
    pub text: String,
}

pub struct Base {
    // ...
    extra: Option<Vec<Component>>,
    // ...
}
```

What I want to do is:

- While deserializing, if the input is a number, return a `Component::String`. This can be done with `visit_i`/`u`/`f64` and friends.
- If the input is a string, return a `Component::String` again. This can be done with `visit_str`/`string`.
- If input is an array `[..]`, deserialize it as usual, but make assign elements in array[1..] to extra of array[0]. This can be done by `visit_seq`.
- If input is a map, let serde derive handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Serde documentation](https://serde.rs) has an example showing how to implement deserializing from [either a string or a structure](https://serde.rs/string-or-struct.html). This is equivalent to your case, just smaller.

The important part is this:

```
fn visit_map<M>(self, visitor: M) -> Result<T, M::Error>
where
    M: MapAccess<'de>,
{
    Deserialize::deserialize(de::value::MapAccessDeserializer::new(visitor))
}
```

This delegates to the built-in deserialization implementation. Since all of your other cases are custom, this should be suitable.

Comment: Thank you <3. The trick was to derive Deserialize as usual for my type and make a wrapper type for the additional deserialization logic with that to delegate.