# How to use Serde to parse a field that might fail to be deserialized without failing the entire deserialization?

Tags: error-handling, rust, deserialization, serde

I am deserializing some JSON objects which come in as requests. The input body is nested, but a certain field is sometimes misformatted for a variety of reasons. In that situation I still want the rest of the object. This doesn't all have to be done through serde; but what is happening now, is that if a single subfield is messed up, the whole request is trashed. I want to somehow still deserialize that result and just mark the field as errored out. How can this be done?

E.g. the data schema might look like:

```
struct BigNested {
    a: Vec<A>,
    b: B, // definition omitted
}

struct A {
    keep_this: Foo,
    trouble: SometimesBad,
}
```

`trouble` is the field that's frequently coming in messed up. I would be happy to (e.g.) turn `trouble` into a `Result<SometimesBad, Whatever>` and process it from there, but I don't know how to get serde to let me do that.

Comment: Have you read [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423)?

Comment: @Shepmaster I haven't seen that answer before but I have been reading the associated documentation for a while (including the `deserialize_with` attribute). However when I was following the associated documentation I ended up writing _so much code_ and felt there must be an easier way.

Comment: *writing so much code and felt there must be an easier way* — and does the linked question show that way? (TL;DR: you can use intermediate automatic implementations of `Serialize` and `Deserialize`).

Comment: @Shepmaster I thought I did, however the issue seems to be with the model of serde's deserializer. I can use a custom type which _correctly_ deserializes the bad data _as_ an error. However it seems to be that the `deserializer` object, which is passed in, is "poisoned" -- it remembers that it hit an error, and any further attempt to use it just returns that _same_ error; it can't understand that the associated bad object is over and it should keep trying.

Comment: (cont) I suspect the issue is https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/464 which is an old issue (2016) opened for this issue, specifically to resolve this issue, and it looks like it was closed without doing it.

Comment: I think I understand why this is the case (serde supports formats which are not self-describing, and this "recovery" is not possible in those cases) but it is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

> certain field is sometimes misformatted

You didn't say how malformed the incoming JSON was. Assuming it's still valid JSON, you can pull this off with [Serde's struct `flatten`](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html) and customized deserialization:

- The customized deserialization is done in a way that never fails for valid JSON input, although it may not return value of expected type if the input has unexpected format.
- But these unexpected fields still need to go somewhere. Serde's struct `flatten` comes in handy here to catch them since *any* JSON snippet can be deserialized to a `HashMap<String, Value>`.

```rust
//# serde = { version = "1.0.103", features = ["derive"] }
//# serde_json = "1.0.44"
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, de::DeserializeOwned};
use serde_json::Value;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct A {
    keep_this: Foo,
    trouble: SometimesBad,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    foo: i32,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct SometimesBad {
    inner: TryParse<Bar>,

    #[serde(flatten)]
    blackhole: HashMap<String, Value>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Bar {
    bar: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum TryParse<T> {
    Parsed(T),
    Unparsed(Value),
    NotPresent
}

impl<'de, T: DeserializeOwned> Deserialize<'de> for TryParse<T> {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        match Option::<Value>::deserialize(deserializer)? {
            None => Ok(TryParse::NotPresent),
            Some(value) => match T::deserialize(&value) {
                Ok(t) => Ok(TryParse::Parsed(t)),
                Err(_) => Ok(TryParse::Unparsed(value)),
            },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let valid = r#"{ "keep_this": { "foo": 1 }, "trouble": { "inner": { "bar": "one"}}}"#;
    println!("{:#?}", serde_json::from_str::<A>(valid));

    let extra_field = r#"{ "keep_this": { "foo": 1 }, "trouble": { "inner": { "bar": "one"}, "extra": 2019}}"#;
    println!("{:#?}", serde_json::from_str::<A>(extra_field));

    let wrong_type = r#"{ "keep_this": { "foo": 1 }, "trouble": { "inner": { "bar": 1}}}"#;
    println!("{:#?}", serde_json::from_str::<A>(wrong_type));

    let missing_field = r#"{ "keep_this": { "foo": 1 }, "trouble": { "inner": { "baz": "one"}}}"#;
    println!("{:#?}", serde_json::from_str::<A>(missing_field));

    let missing_inner = r#"{ "keep_this": { "foo": 1 }, "trouble": { "whatever": { "bar": "one"}}}"#;
    println!("{:#?}", serde_json::from_str::<A>(missing_inner));
}
```

(The credit isn't all mine. [Serde's issue 1583](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1583) basically has everything.)