# How to access nested enums without full match syntax

Tags: rust, struct, enums, nested, serde

I am using the `Serde` crate to deserialise a JSON file, which has a nested structure like this:

```
struct Nested {
    a: Vec<Foo>,
    b: u8,
}

struct Foo {
    c: Bar,
    d: Vec<f32>,
}

Struct Bar {
    e: u32,
    f: String,
}
```

Part of the applications purpose is to check for missing parameters (or incorrect types in parameters), and then display a nicely printed list of errors found in the file, so I need to handle the structure missing parameters or wrongly typed.

I came across [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254690/how-to-use-serde-to-parse-a-field-that-might-fail-to-be-deserialized-without-fai) that helped solved my issue, by wrapping each parameter in an enum result that contains the value if it passed, the value if it failed, or a final enum if it was missing (since the nested structures might also be missing I wrapped them in the same enum):

```
pub enum TryParse<T> {
    Parsed(T),
    Unparsed(Value),
    NotPresent
}

struct Nested {
    a: TryParse<Vec<Foo>>,
    b: TryParse<u8>,
}

struct Foo {
    c: TryParse<Bar>,
    d: TryParse<Vec<f32>>,
}

Struct Bar {
    e: TryParse<u32>,
    f: TryParse<String>,
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to access them now without unpacking every step into a match statement. For example, I can access B very easily:

```
    match file.b {
        Parsed(val) => {println!("Got parameter of {}", val)},
        Unparsed(val) => {println!("Invalid type: {:?}", val)}
        NotPresent => {println!("b not found")},
    };
```

However, I'm not sure how to access the nested ones (C D E and F). I can't use Unwrap or expect since this isn't technically a 'Result', so how do I unpack these?:

```
if file.a.c.e.Parsed() && file.a.c.e == 32 {... //invalid
if file.a.d && file.a.d.len() == 6... //invalid
```

I know in a way this flies against rust's 'handle every outcome' philosophy, and I want to handle them, but I want to know if there is a nicer way than 400 nested match statements (the above example is very simplified, the files I am using have up to 6 nested layers, each parameter in the top node has at least 3 layers, some are vectors as well)…

Perhaps I need to implement a function similar to unwrap() on my 'TryParse'? or would it be better to wrap each parameter in a 'Result', extend that with the deserialise trait, and then somehow store the error in the Err option that says if it was a type error or missing parameter?

---

### EDIT

I tried adding the following, some of which works and some of which does not:

```
impl <T> TryParse<T> {
    pub fn is_ok(self) -> bool { //works
        match self {
            Self::Parsed(_t) => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
    pub fn is_absent(self) -> bool { //works
        match self {
            Self::NotPresent => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
    pub fn is_invalid(self) -> bool { //works
        match self {
            Self::Unparsed(_) => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
    pub fn get(self) -> Result<T, dyn Error> { //doesnt work
        match self {
            Self::Parsed(t) => Ok(t),
            Self::Unparsed(e) => Err(e),
            Self::NotPresent => Err("Invalid")
        }
    }
}
```

I can't believe it is this hard just to get the result, should I just avoid nested enums or get rid of the TryParse enums/ functions all together and wrap everything in a result, so the user simply knows if it worked or didn't work (but no explanation why it failed)

Comment: I don't know how nice you want your error messages, but I'm wondering if you couldn't achieve your goals by: a) generating a JSON schema for your nested structs with the schemars create, and b) checking whether your JSON is valid under the schema with the valico crate.

Comment: If you are ok with unstable features, you can implement [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/ops/trait.Try.html) on your enums, allowing you to use `?` to unpack them.

Comment: @Jmb do I need to create a custom implementation/function to use the 'Try' syntax or can I just use a trait attached to the enum? with an enum of more than 2 values, how does it know which value to unpack?

Comment: You need to implement the [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait for your enums. This defines a [`branch`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/ops/trait.Try.html#tymethod.branch) method which tells it which value to unpack or return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be the most Rust-y way of doing it, but for those like me moving from another language like C/Python/C++, this is the way I have done it that still allows me to quickly validate if I have an error and use the match syntax to handle it. Thanks to @Chayim Friedman for assisting with this, his way is probably better but this made the most sense for me:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum TryParse<T> {
    Parsed(T),
    Unparsed(Value),
    NotPresent
}

impl<'de, T: DeserializeOwned> Deserialize<'de> for TryParse<T> {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        match Option::<Value>::deserialize(deserializer)? {
            None => Ok(TryParse::NotPresent),
            Some(value) => match T::deserialize(&value) {
                Ok(t) => Ok(TryParse::Parsed(t)),
                Err(_) => Ok(TryParse::Unparsed(value)),
            },
        }
    }
}

impl <T> TryParse<T> {
    //pub fn is_ok(self) -> bool {   ---> Use get().is_ok(), built into result
    //  match self {
    //      Self::Parsed(_t) => true,
    //      _ => false,
    //  }
    //}
    pub fn is_absent(self) -> bool {
        match self {
            Self::NotPresent => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
    pub fn is_invalid(self) -> bool {
        match self {
            Self::Unparsed(_) => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
    pub fn get(&self) -> Result<&T, String> {
        match self {
            Self::Parsed(t) => Ok(t),
            Self::Unparsed(v) => Err(format!("Unable to Parse {:?}", v)),
            Self::NotPresent => Err("Parameter not Present".to_string())
        }
    }
    // pub fn get_direct(&self) -> &T {
    //     match self {
    //         Self::Parsed(t) => t,
    //         _ => panic!("Can't get this value!"),
    //     }
    // }
}

match &nested.a.get().unwrap()[1].c.get.expect("Missing C Parameter").e{
        Parsed(val) => {println!("Got value of E: {}", val)},
        Unparsed(val) => {println!("Invalid Type: {:?}", val)}
        NotPresent => {println!("Param E Not Found")},
    };

//Note the use of '&' at the beginning because we need to borrow a reference to it
```

I know I need to change my mindset to use the rust way of thinking, and I am completely open to other suggestions if they can demonstrate some working code.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `unwrap()` is one possibility. Using `Result` is another, with a custom error type. You can deserialize directly into result with [`#[serde(deserialize_with = "...")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with), or using a newtype wrapper.

However, a not-enough-used power of pattern matching is nested patterns. For example, instead of `if file.a.c.e.Parsed() && file.a.c.e == 32` you can write:

```rust
if let TryParse::Parsed(a) = &file.a {
    // Unfortunately we cannot combine this `if let` with the surrounding `if let`,
    // because `Vec` doesn't support pattern matching (currently).
    if let TryParsed::Parsed(
        [Foo {
            c:
                TryParse::Parsed(Bar {
                    e: TryParse::Parsed(32),
                    ..
                }),
            ..
        }, ..],
    ) = a.as_slice()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The second option seems very complicated and almost as much code as a full match syntax, but I'm interested in using the `Result`. How would that work? and would I have to attach  `#[serde(deserialize_with = "...")]` for every parameter in each structure or can I just attach it to the structs?

Comment: @birdistheword99 I actually like the pattern matching more :) If you use `Result` directly, you have to attach it to each field. However, you can wrap `Result` with a newtype struct, and use a custom `Deserialize` impl for it.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to rust, how do I wrap result to achieve this? I have managed to implement a 'Is valid' function that returns a bool if the value is valid, but I tried implementing a 'get' function to get the value and I just cant find a way, compiler complains if I try to return a result

Comment: @birdistheword99 `pub struct MyResult<T>(pub Result<T, MyError>); impl<'de, T> serde::Deserialize<'de> for MyResult<T> where T: serde::Deserialize<'de> { ... }`.

Comment: inside those brackets I implemented deserialise, but when I try to return the value wrapped in `Ok(t)` or `Err(value)`, I get all kinds of errors about `mismatched types, expected struct MyResult found Type Parameter T`, and `expected associated type, found struct MyError`.

Still not sure how to actually return the value, getting very frustrated with rust!

Comment: ```pub struct MyResult<T>(pub Result<T,  ConfigError>);
impl<'de, T> Deserialize<'de> for MyResult<T> where T: Deserialize<'de> {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<MyResult<T>, ConfigError> {
        match Option::<Value>::deserialize(deserializer)? {
            None => Err(ConfigError::new("Missing Paramater")),
            Some(value) => match T::deserialize(&value) {
                Ok(t) => Ok(t),
                Err(_) => Err(ConfigError::new("Wrong Type")),
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @birdistheword99 If you have problems, you can ask a new SO question. A question should be focused on one thing only.

Comment: Ok fair enough, its still related to the same problem, I haven't solved this yet, but I will ask another question (or probably just write the parser in C and pass the resulting C-Struct to rust, as this is getting overly complicated for such a simple task) - Thank you for your help though