# How do I pass a type bounded by a trait to Serde's deserialize_with?

Tags: rust, deserialization, traits, serde

A type satisfying `MyTrait` is supposed to be passed to `deserialize_data` specified by `deserialize_with`. Here is my [sample code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=15PQMNFhvirNkGBzSj7k71vY2n9Qa6mUS1):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer}; // 1.0.117
use serde_json; // 1.0.59

type Item = Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;
pub trait MyTrait {
    fn method(ind: &str) -> Item;
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct S<T>
where
    T: MyTrait + ?Sized, // intend to pass a type T satisfying `MyTrait` to function `deserialize_data`,
{
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_data")]
    //#[serde(bound( deserialize = "T: MyTrait,  for<'de2> T: Deserialize<'de2>" ))]
    pub data: String,
}

fn deserialize_data<'de, D, T>(d: D) -> Result<String, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let ind = <&str>::deserialize(d).unwrap();
    match T::method(ind) {
        Ok(data) => Ok(data),
        Err(e) => Err(serde::de::Error::custom(format_args!("invalid type."))),
    }
}

struct A;
impl MyTrait for A {
    fn method(_ind: &str) -> Item {
        // to make it simple, return constant
        Ok("method".to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = r#"{"data": "string"}"#;
    let ob: S<A> = serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap();
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
  --> src/main.rs:10:14
   |
10 | pub struct S<T>
   |              ^ unused parameter
   |
   = help: consider removing `T`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
```

I do use `T`, and `PhantomData` doesn't help much.
One of the obvious way may be using `struct A` and its implemented method as crate or something then importing them. This, unfortunately, doesn't apply to my case, so I seek to pass a struct type to `deserialize_data` and achieve that.

Comment: It sounds like your problem would be solved following [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the code to compile, you need to:

- use `T` in `struct S<T>`, for example with `PhantomData`.
- explicitly pass `T` to `deserialize_data` using the turbofish operator `::<>`.
- add the appropriate trait bounds to the `T` generic type in `deserialize_data()`, such as `MyTrait`.

For example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=79ff2017e5e6329c508059721c39663a)):

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct S<T>
where
    T: MyTrait + ?Sized,
{
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_data::<_, T>")]
    pub data: String,
    marker: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}

fn deserialize_data<'de, D, T>(d: D) -> Result<String, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
    T: MyTrait + ?Sized,
{
    // ...
}
```