# Can I serialize a subset of fields and use a function to deserialize the other fields without manually implementing Serialize or Deserialize?

Tags: rust, serde

I have the following struct

```rust
struct S {
    value: f32,
    square: f32,
}
```

I would like to derive `square` from `value` in the `new(value)`:

```rust
impl S {
    fn new(value: f32) -> Self {
        Self { value, square: value.powi(2) }
    }
}
```

Can I use `value` field only to serialize the struct and use `new(value)` to deserialize the whole thing without manually implementing `Serialize`/`Deserialize` traits?

Comment: what is the point of that? if you do that then deserialization wouldn't be safe

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46755370/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1185c61776f1413aac08b5d28885a7d8).

Comment: @DanielA.White imagine you have a JSON input in the form of `{"value": 1.23}` which should be enough to reconstruct the whole struct. Probably it is my conceptual mis-understanding, but I see no sense ask user to provide fully-constructed struct.

Comment: Ok then just use `Option<T>`

Comment: @Stepmaster is it not about isolated field transformation, it is about deriving some fields from other ones

Comment: @hombit yes, and the [fully working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1185c61776f1413aac08b5d28885a7d8) I provided shows that exactly.

Comment: @DanielA.White `Option` is not an option, because `square` is closely connected to the `value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753955/how-to-transform-fields-during-deserialization-using-serde)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement deserialization with the [`#[serde(from = "FromType")]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#from) attribute. If the transformation can fail, there is also the `try_from` attribute.

> Deserialize this type by deserializing into `FromType`, then converting. This type must implement `From<FromType>`, and `FromType` must implement `Deserialize`.

Serializing a subset of fields can be achieved by applying the [`#[serde(skip)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#skip) annotation on the fields you want to omit.

Applied to your use case a solution looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(from = "DeserS")]
struct S {
    value: f32,
    #[serde(skip)]
    square: f32,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct DeserS {
    value: f32,
}

impl From<DeserS> for S {
    fn from(tmp: DeserS) -> Self {
        Self {
            value: tmp.value,
            square: tmp.value.powi(2),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae6ca1e4179b7f0782ae3ae0fc4bd579)